# How can I test a function that takes record as a parameter?

Tags: python, django, pytest

I need to write a test for a function `post_log_filter(record)` in the file `my_logging.py`

`#my_logging.py`

```
import os
import sys
import traceback


log_format = '[%(levelname)s] %(asctime)s %(context)s %(pathname)s:%(lineno)d: %(message)s'
log_time_format = '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z'

def post_log_filter(record):
    # filter out undesirable logs
    logs_to_omit = [
        {'filename': 'basehttp.py', 'funcName': 'log_message'},  # annoying logging any response to sys.stderr (even if status is 200)
        {'filename': 'options.py', 'funcName': 'construct_change_message'},  # logging `Key not found` if a checkbox was unchecked and isn't present in POST data
    ]
    if any([bool(record.__dict__.viewitems() >= r.viewitems()) for r in logs_to_omit]):
        return False

    return True
```

The test that I have written is:

`test_my_logging.py`

```
from django.utils.unittest import TestCase
from my_logging import *
import collections
import mock
from mock import patch
import logging
LOGGER = logging.getLogger(__name__)
log_format = '[%(levelname)s] %(asctime)s %(context)s %(pathname)s:%(lineno)d: %(message)s'
log_time_format = '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z'


class TestMyLogging(TestCase):
    def test_post_log_filter(self):
        self.assertEqual(True, post_log_filter(logging.LogRecord(None, None, None, None, msg=None, args=None, exc_info=None, func=None)))
    
    def test_post_log_filter_false(self):
        record = logging.Formatter([
            {'filename': 'basehttp.py', 'funcName': 'log_message'},  # annoying logging any response to sys.stderr (even if status is 200)
            {'filename': 'options.py', 'funcName': 'construct_change_message'},  # logging `Key not found` if a checkbox was unchecked and isn't present in POST data
        ])
        self.assertEqual(False, post_log_filter(record))
```

I am testing it for two cases.
For True:
No matter what I pass for `post_log_filter()`, I get true. So the first test passes.

I don't know what I'm doing wrongly when passing `record` for testing for `False`, I get `True` for this as well. So, the test fails.

How would you recommend me pass the record so I get `False`.
I am not allowed to change `my_logging.py`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution.
Modifying the record as below now tests for `False`.

```
def test_post_log_filter_false(self):
    record = logging.makeLogRecord({'filename': 'basehttp.py', 'funcName': 'log_message'})
    self.assertEqual(False, post_log_filter(record))
```

Both test passes.